# How to check if QSound could play a sound successfully

Tags: qt, audio

Is there a way to check whether `QSound::play()` was successful? This means, the file was found, it is in a valid format, and QSound managed to start playing it.

This would be especially important because QSound cannot play all types of formats, sample rates, etc.

A hack would be to start the sound, and after a very short delay check `isFinished()`, but it only works for looped sounds.

Is there any better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be any way of checking that for QSound. Qt docs state:

> The QSound class provides a method to play **.wav** sound files

So the format must be .wav, but I think it just doesn't play if it is invalid.

However, you could try using the QSoundEffect class instead. You set the source with a QUrl path and then you can call the function status() to see if it loaded correctly. This may return Error if it's not the right format, but you'd have to try it and see.

If that still doesn't work, there's QMediaPlayer, though it may not start playback as quickly as QSoundEffect, but can report a variety of errors, such as FormatError, ResourceError, NetworkError etc.